# How to update an index inside an array with hooks without hitting "Error: Too many re-renders."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have an array of cells that I need to update based on some user input from a socket server. But whenever I try to update an index using useState(), react complains about "Error: Too many re-renders.". I tried adding a state to indicate that the grid has changed, but that still produces the same error. Please help me :<

```
const GameUI = ({ height, width }) => {
  const [grid, setGrid] = React.useState([]);
  const [didUpdate, setDidUpdate] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    for (let index = 0; index < 64; index++) {
      const gridItem = <GridSquare key={`${index}`} color="" />;
      setGrid((oldArray) => [...oldArray, gridItem]);
    }
  }, []);

  //not re-rendering the modified component
  const handleChange = () => {
    let board = [...grid]
    board[1] = <GridSquare key={`${0}${1}`} color="1" />;
    setGrid(board)
    // let count = didUpdate;
    // count += 1
    // setDidUpdate(count)
  };

  // handleChange();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GridBoard grid={grid} />
      <ScoreBoard />
      <Players />
      {handleChange()}
      {/* <MessagePopup /> */}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: the grid]

[image: the errors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you change a state provided from the `useState` hook, it re-renders your component. You are calling `handleChange` on every render, which is calling your `setGrid` state hook. Therefore, you are rendering your component infinitely.

When do you actually need to call `handleChange`? Every animation frame? Every action event of some kind? Create an appropriate useEffect or useCallback hook (that includes used dependencies [array] as the second parameter), apply the appropriate event to your method and trigger it accordingly. If you go with a useEffect, don't forget to return a function that disables the event handling when the component is eventually unmounted or else you will have duplicate events triggering every time it gets remounted in the same application.

Comment: Thank you! I took out the function handleChange() outside of useEffect and attached to a button.